# Why CAPTCHA verification?

Tags: discussion, captcha

I was surprised by seeing the site asking for CAPTCHA verification. I am curious that what prompts MSE to ask a user to confirm that they are not Bots. What is the intention of site to verify that user is human?

Comment: Were you logged in?--> https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355670/

Comment: You know that spam bots are a real thing, right?

Comment: The most common situation when I've been prompted to perform a CAPTCHA verification is when I've had a draft Answer "in progress" for a substantial time (hours), and when I submit the post I most likely see that, asking me to "confirm" I'm human.  Was that the occasion for you?

Comment: @hardmath: this has been the case with me many times. I sometimes draft a long answer in a text editor and then copy paste here. Maybe the site thinks it is impossible for humans to write a long answer in a sec and click submit.

Comment: BTW, Captcha is only a tiny element in Stack Exchange's war on spam & abusive posts. As well as the anti-spam measures in the system software and manual actions taken by SE staff, a lot of spam is handled by ordinary SE members & moderators, both manually and using sophisticated software they've created. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291301/334566 for details & numerous relevant links.

Answer (score 2):

I actually had the same experience in these cases. For my prompt, I went to make a draft of my question and I leave because of my bad Internet Connection. I come back with a good one and reviewed and posted, but then CAPTCHA arrives. It's very likely that some have experienced it by this reason, especially [**@hardmath**](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3111/hardmath) who has posted a comment here on his experience.

To make sure that you are not some automated system that creates spam, abuse and violating certain rules, Stack Exchange in fact brings CAPTCHA as a protection.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it is a global StackExchange policy to prompt users with a CAPTCHA if they take more than 40 minutes writing a post, regardless of all prior reputation gains or good behavior across sites.

They [apparently claimed to have removed this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38008/eliminate-the-captcha-on-long-questions-answers/38232#38232) in 2010, but appear to have reinstated it for no clear reason despite [multiple](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348240/do-not-repeatedly-require-trusted-contributors-to-solve-captchas-when-they-attem) [requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333673/has-the-maximum-time-threshold-for-question-captchas-been-reintroduced-recently) to change this "feature".

Comment: The claim of 40 minutes does not match my experience - I have written many answers which have taken longer than 40 minutes and only received a CAPTCHA challenge on a very small number of these. hardmath's comment on the main question aligns closest with my experience - generally I need to have had a particular answer up for a rather long amount of time (hours, at least) to encounter that dialog.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification - almost all my questions are drafted for hours, so I’d never had personal verification of the lower bound.